# discord.py JSON TypeError

Tags: python, json, discord.py

So I been making a discord giveaway bot, and I made a small database for storage. But whenever I run it, I shows a Type Error 
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

````
async def update_db(guild, giveaway):
   if not f"{guild.id}" in giveaway:
       giveaway[str(guild.id)] = {}
       giveaway[str(guild.id)]["giveaway_db_1"] = []
   else:
       return

async def add_giveaway_db(guild, giveaway, id):
   giveaway[str(guild.id)]["giveaway_db_1"].append({id:[]})
async def remove_giveaway_db(guild, giveaway, id):
   giveaway[str(guild.id)]["giveaway_db_1"].remove(id)
async def remove_giveaway_attender_db(guild, giveaway, id, user):
   giveaway[str(guild.id)]["giveaway_db_1"][str(id)].remove(user)
async def add_giveaway_attender_db(guild, giveaway, id, user):
   giveaway[str(guild.id)]["giveaway_db_1"][str(id)].append(user)```
````

Comment: Can you please add the full traceback of the error?

Comment: With constructs such as `giveaway[a][b][c].remove(user)` there is probably one indexing level that needs an integer index rather than a string. Split the code into `ga=giveaway[a]; gb=ga[b]; gc=gb[c]` (on separate lines) to figure out which one causes the error.

Comment: ok let me try that